# How is this C++ Reference Initialization Legal?

Tags: c++, variables, reference, constants

I'm currently reading c++ Primer and in one of the exercises, it shows 2 types of reference initializations, one const and and one not, and in the one const, the reference points to 0.. I thought references could only point to objects!!

```
   int i = -1, &r = 0;         // illegal, r must refer to an object.

   const int i = -1, &r = 0;   // legal.
```

So the first one, int  variable  i is -1.  Then int reference r refers to 0 which is 
                                         invalid,gotcha

Now in the second one, const int i = -1, then const reference r = 0.. How?

I know references can't be const, the const is what the reference is referring to, and the book said that const references can refer to both const and non const objects(of the same type). This still doesn't explain why it can point to 0, which is not an object at all..

I'm not sure how the second statement is valid, someone please explain!

Comment: Do you know the terms rvalue and lvalue? These determine what references are allowed to bind to (along with type).

Comment: @NirFriedman when asking this, I didn't but when it got answered, I googled them and now I do.. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
const int &r = 0;
```

a temporary object is created with the value 0, and then `r` is bound to that object. This is allowed because a `const` reference is allowed to bind to an rvalue. It also works with an rvalue reference:

```
int&& r = 0;  // ok
```

However, it won't work with `int&` because an `int&` variable can only bind to an lvalue.

Note that the temporary object that the reference binds to will live until the reference goes out of scope. See https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: OK so const references can bind to anything that can be converted to a const reference but int references can only bind with int, period, ?

Comment: @iMarioOfficial It's possible to use as an initializer for `int&` some object that has a conversion operator to `int&`. The bottom line is that it must be possible to obtain an lvalue for the initialization.

Comment: Ohh ok I just read up on lvalue and rvalue and I get it now, thanks!

Comment: This answer would be improved with a reference to reference lifetime extension; why this is somewhat safe.

Answer (score 1):

C++ specifically allows that an rvalue be bound to a const lvalue reference, so this is perfectly standard-conforming:

```
const int &r = 0;
```

[Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue)

> - An rvalue may be used to initialize a **const lvalue reference**, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends.